# JavaFX image loading memory leak?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to build an application for "gesture drawing", which is basically just a slideshow of images in set intervals. I noticed that whenever I load a new image that's for instance less than 1MB the memory usage of my app increases by over 20MB, every time a new image loads.

I've tried two approaches, the first one was with a custom "ImagePane" - in order to be able to resize the image with the window - that loads the given image in its style sheet (`-fx-background-image`), and the second one is using a regular ImageView using the `setImage()` method. In both cases I noticed significant memory increase.

Now my question is: Is that normal behaviour, a known memory leak or am I doing something wrong? I can provide the whole code if necessary, it's just a big prototype mess at the moment though...

Comment: Are you comparing the image *file* size to the memory required to display the image? These are completely different things.

Comment: Well, I know they are, but I still can't see why the RAM usage would increase by over 20MB everytime a 800kb 2000x3000 image gets loaded.

Comment: 2000x3000 = 6 million pixels. Each pixel is represented by 4 bytes (one each for red, green, blue, and alpha). 4 bytes x 6 million pixels = 24 million bytes. Seems to make sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, but why does it keep adding up?

Comment: Because you keep loading more images? I don't really understand what you think the problem is.

Comment: Why are the images kept in memory then... that's my issue.

Comment: Presumably because the gc hasn't run yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. When you load a new image, it will consume approximately 4 bytes per pixel. As long as you don't accidentally keep references to images you are no longer using, they will become eligible for garbage collection in the normal way. You have little control over when the garbage collector will reclaim the memory, and you should leave that up to the JVM.